# Selenium: how to write xpath for an html?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to write `xpath` for the below`html` code?

```
<li>
    <a href="/parade/storeus/browse/Home-Accents-Radios/_/N-1c7kmv">
        Radios
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: following code will check for the given condition in xpath.

Here the condition is whether this given text is there in between the tag 'a' are not.

```
//a[contains(text(),'Radios')]
```

Comment: Mind explain bit more ?

Comment: It will compare the text in between the tag 'a'. So you can try that xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath:

```
//a[@href='/storeus/browse/Home-Accents-Radios/_/N-1c7kmv'];
```

or else you can use linktext to identify this element. i.e

```
driver.findelement(By.linktext("Radios"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Saritha G is right - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31559632/2131257).

You can also use

`//a[text()='Radios')]`

if this is exactly the same text as expected. Or use other xpath functions like starts-with(), ends-with() etc. if you want. It depends on what you want to check.